# Fast Matrix Multiplication and Neural Networks

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

I've used neural networks a little, but not much.  So as an attempt to increase my level of comfort, I decided to use one to play around with one of my favorite math problems: fast matrix multiplication.
The standard algorithm takes O(n^3) to multiply two nxn matrices.  The Strassen algorithm does it in O(n^2.8).  The algorithms based off of work by Coppersmith and Winograd get down to O(n^2.373) but are impractical due to the large constant factor.
There's a lot of wiggle room in between the latter two.  In particular, if you can multiply two 4x4 matrices using 48 multiply operations or less, you've done better than Strassen.

So here's my setup: I have two (pseudo-randomly generated) nxn matrices, A and B.  One neural network takes NMULT linear combinations of elements of A and NMULT linear combinations of B, multiplies them together pointwise and then takes n^2 linear combinations of the output, trying to reconstruct the product AB.  The loss is the sum-of-squares error over the entries.
The adversarial network takes two random matrices A' and B', and outputs softsign(A' + A_offset) and softsign(B' + B_offset), with loss function = -1 * sum-of-squares error of the other network.

I alternate between 3 steps of training: training the fast-matrix-multiply network on random input matrices A and B, training the adversarial network on random input matrices A' and B', and training the fmm network on the output of the adversarial network.

It doesn't work.  Not only can I not do better than Strassen, I can't even reproduce basic matrix multiplication!  That is, if I take n = 2 and NMULT = 8, I don't get down to 0 error.

I know there are other (potentially better) ways of solving this problem than using neural networks -- I'm only doing this as a learning method.  Can anyone give me suggestions as to how to fix this?

See code below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

epochs=1000
tot_batch = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01

MATRIX_SIZE = 2
NMULTS = 8

nvals = MATRIX_SIZE * MATRIX_SIZE

# These are the inputs to the adversarial NN generating our input matrices A&B.
a_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nvals])
b_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nvals])

adv_a_icpt = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nvals]))
adv_b_icpt = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nvals]))

a_vector = tf.nn.softsign(a_inputs + adv_a_icpt)
b_vector = tf.nn.softsign(b_inputs + adv_b_icpt)

# These are the two adversarial matrices we are multiplying; all entries
# are in [-1, 1]. This makes normalizing the error easier.
a_matrix = tf.reshape(a_vector, [-1, MATRIX_SIZE, MATRIX_SIZE])
b_matrix = tf.reshape(b_vector, [-1, MATRIX_SIZE, MATRIX_SIZE])

# This is the product A * B.
m_matrix = tf.matmul(a_matrix, b_matrix)

# This is what the fast-matrix-multiply NN will be predicting.
m_vector = tf.reshape(m_matrix, [-1, nvals])

fmm_a_wts = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nvals, NMULTS]))
fmm_b_wts = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nvals, NMULTS]))
fmm_output_wts = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([NMULTS, nvals]))

# This is the output of the fast-matrix-multiply NN.
def fmm_output(input_a_vec, input_b_vec):
  hidden_a_inputs = tf.matmul(input_a_vec, fmm_a_wts)
  hidden_b_inputs = tf.matmul(input_b_vec, fmm_b_wts)
  hidden_output = tf.multiply(hidden_a_inputs, hidden_b_inputs) 
  return tf.matmul(hidden_output, fmm_output_wts)

# Treat each element of the input arrays as having a variance of O(1). Then
# the output array elements have a variance of O(MATRIX_SIZE).
loss_adv = tf.divide(
    tf.losses.mean_squared_error(m_vector, fmm_output(a_vector, b_vector)),
    MATRIX_SIZE)
abs_err_vec_adv = tf.abs(tf.subtract(m_vector, fmm_output(a_vector, b_vector)))
mean_abs_err_adv = tf.reduce_mean(abs_err_vec_adv, reduction_indices=[1])

m_rand = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(a_inputs, [-1, MATRIX_SIZE, MATRIX_SIZE]),
                   tf.reshape(b_inputs, [-1, MATRIX_SIZE, MATRIX_SIZE]))
loss_rand = tf.divide(
    tf.losses.mean_squared_error(tf.reshape(m_rand, [-1, nvals]),
                                 fmm_output(a_inputs, b_inputs)),
    MATRIX_SIZE) 


optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

train_ADV = optimizer.minimize(-loss_adv,
                               var_list=[adv_a_wts, adv_b_wts,
                                         adv_a_icpt, adv_b_icpt])

train_FMMA = optimizer.minimize(loss_adv,
                                var_list=[fmm_a_wts, fmm_b_wts,
                                          fmm_output_wts])

train_FMMR = optimizer.minimize(loss_rand,
                                var_list=[fmm_a_wts, fmm_b_wts,
                                          fmm_output_wts])


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)

  adv_batch_size = 100
  fmm_batch_size = 100

  for epoch in range(epochs):
    adv_loss = 0.0
    rand_loss = 0.0
    for i in range(tot_batch):
      # Run the fast-matrix-multiply NN training against random inputs.
      batch_a_inputs = np.random.uniform(low=-1., size=[fmm_batch_size, nvals])
      batch_b_inputs = np.random.uniform(low=-1., size=[fmm_batch_size, nvals])
      _, rerr = sess.run([train_FMMR, loss_rand],
                         feed_dict={ a_inputs : batch_a_inputs,
                                     b_inputs : batch_b_inputs })

      # Run the adversarial NN training.
      batch_a_inputs = np.random.normal(size=[adv_batch_size, nvals])
      batch_b_inputs = np.random.normal(size=[adv_batch_size, nvals])
      sess.run(train_ADV, feed_dict={ a_inputs : batch_a_inputs,
                                      b_inputs : batch_b_inputs })

      # Run the fast-matrix-multiply NN training against adversarial inputs.
      batch_a_inputs = np.random.normal(size=[fmm_batch_size, nvals])
      batch_b_inputs = np.random.normal(size=[fmm_batch_size, nvals])
      _, aerr, mae = sess.run([train_FMMA, loss_adv, mean_abs_err_adv],
                         feed_dict={ a_inputs : batch_a_inputs,
                                     b_inputs : batch_b_inputs })

      adv_loss += aerr / tot_batch
      rand_loss += 3.0 * rerr / tot_batch
      if i % 200 == 0:
        print("Batch " + str(i) + ", mean abs error: " + str(mae[0:4]))
    print("Epoch: " + str(epoch) + ", rand loss = " + str(rand_loss) +
          ", adv loss = " + str(adv_loss))
```

Answer (score 2):

To find (or rediscover) a matrix multiplication algorithm is equivalent to solve the system of [Brent Equations](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pub/pub002.html).

For the `n*n` matrix product with `k` elementary multiplications, the system has `n^6` equations with a sum of `k` 3-factor products. Thus, the system is highly non-linear and has `3k n^2` unknowns. In [practice](http://www.gregorybard.com/papers/early_release.pdf), it is very hard to find solutions beyond the `2*2` case. For `2*2`, there are `64` equations with seven products each. For `3*3`, there are `729` equations with `23` products each.

Researchers have tried to discover matrix multiplication algorithms for small-factor matrices for [decades.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ef42/701ae41832ab90bacc8f08fc1c2812b24490.pdf) It would be possible but really more than surprising, if a neural network would beat the whole science community.

In spite of my doubts, a [related research](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07227) succeeded to rediscover the algorithms for 2x2 and 3x3 using neural networks.

Comment: I am well aware of all of this -- I do actually follow the latest fast matrix multiplication results.  I'm _not_ expecting to beat what is known.  What I was hoping to do was e.g. rediscover Strassen.  Instead I find that I can't even duplicate the basic 8-step 2x2x2 multiply.  This is a little surprising to me, and I would have thought that some (relatively simple) neural network techniques would find that solution.

Comment: Incidentally, you've missed this interesting reference: http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~odedsc/papers/SPAA17-MatMul-a-Little-Faster.pdf

Comment: Also this one, which is much more along the lines of what I was hoping for: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01372.pdf

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Could it be that stochastic methods are best suited for convex optimization problems? The search space for matrix multiplication algorithms seems to be scattered with local optima which are hard to circumvent.